# GPT-3.5 embedds but GPT-4 doesn't?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I am experiencing a bizarr problem. In my chat application which is able to download websites for documentation interaction, I am able to initalise the chat function properly with 3.5 turbo but when I change the model to 4, the app isn't able to access the website/documentation. GPT4 used to work but now it doesn't.

There are no other changes to the code exept commenting out the undesired model.

Has anyone else experienced this, and does anyone have a possible solution?[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKMYu.jpg)

Comment: If you make a simple request (e.g., *This is a test*) to the Chat Completions API using the `gpt-4` model, do you get a response? If you get an error, which error exactly do you get?

Comment: Hi @RokBenko ,  thanks for joining the discussion. No there isn't an error message rather the I run 3.5 turbo model is it able to interact with the embedded test data while gpt 4 model isn't able to interact. Test data is scrapped from my personal website. If the script can give me info about the website is passes the test, if that makes sense. Is there an alternative testing method which can force an error? 

Comment: Have you ever made any payment for your OpenAI API usage?

Comment: @RokBenko I am assuming so since I can still use 3.5, has something changed? The amount of money which will be invoiced to Openai has plummeted since this problem has arisen. I tried to contact openai but the only things I was able to figure out is how to report a bug...

Comment: I was thinking that you might not have access to the GPT-4 API (see my [past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773786/cant-access-gpt-4-model-via-python-api-although-gpt-3-5-works/76673502#76673502)). That's why I asked you that.

Comment: @RokBenko I understand. I think the old option is to contact sales department but it's a not very efficient approach. If I find a solution I'll post it. Cheers guys