# How to access internet by Bing with OpenAi from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Using GPT-4 with ChatGPT is it possible to access the web through Bing? I connected OpenAI API with Google Sheets, but the answer to my prompts was there would be no internet access possible.

Is it in general so, that OpenAI can't run Bing from Google Sheets? Or do I something wrong and there is a way to let OpenAI access internet from Google Sheets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API: Why can't I access GPT-4 models via API, although GPT-3.5 models work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773786/openai-api-why-cant-i-access-gpt-4-models-via-api-although-gpt-3-5-models-wor)

Comment: No, I'm interesting explicitely for an internet access by Bing. The model works in general, it isn't a problem.